# How to redirect a specific print statement to a text file in python

Tags: python

I am using the below statements to redirect the output of python program to a log_file and it works.

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(log_file, 'a', buffering=1)
```

But, I would like to pass one or two specific print statements to another flat file(let's suppose sample_file.txt). How can I do that ?

Comment: You can open a file in `append mode` and write your data in it: `with open("sample_file.txt", "a") as f: f.write("hello world!\n")`

Comment: You might want to use the `logging` module in your project.

Comment: python2 or python3?

Comment: I am using Python 2.6.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On older Python's, you can use the 'chevron print' form of the [print statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt) to print from a specific print statement to a file:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 19 2016, 07:22:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f=open('/tmp/file.txt','a')
>>> print "hello"
hello
>>> print >>f, 'hello'
>>> f.close()
>>> open('/tmp/file.txt').read()
'hello\n'
```

The form `print >>fh` prints what follows to the file handle `fh`

Or import the print function in Python 2 to get the ability to add a file handle to the print.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python3, you can optionally pass a fileobject to your print function. Like this:

```
>>> f = open('sample_file.txt', 'w')
>>> print("hello", file = f)
>>> print("hello1", file = f)
>>> print("hello2", file = f)
>>> f.close()
```

Or, even better, use context manager.

```
>>> with open('etc.txt','w') as f:
...     print("hello", file = f)
...     print("hello2", file = f)
...     print("hello2", file = f)
```

In python2, you can use this feature as well. But you need to import the `print()` function from python3. Add this import statement.

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Well, it will. you have to import the function from python3. just add the line `from __future__ import print_function` among the imports  of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted to append new lines to an existing text file, you could modify your code as such, quite simply:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(log_file, 'a', buffering=1)
with open("sample_file.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write("line 1\n")
    f.write("line 2\n")
```

Note that the file `"sample_file.txt"` will be edited in whatever folder/directory the Python file is run in, unless you change it to specify a full (or relative) path.

Comment: @rawse - Which version of python are you using? I have run the code in my environment (excluding the log file print), and it works as intended. However, I had forgot to add a new line character to the end of my two lines, which I have corrected.

Comment: I have got the syntax error when I tried the same.   `sys.stdout = open('/opt/test/test_user/data/PLANNING_%s_%s_%s.etab' % (type, period, self.now), 'a', buffering=1) with open('/opt/test/test_user/data/SUB_PLANNING_%s_%s_%s.etab'' % (type, period, self.now), 'a') as e:`
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Why not use `print` rather than `write`, especially as the question says they wish to "print statements to another file"

Answer (score 0):

Elegant solution would be using a context manager in the following manner

```
print("hello")  # Prints to the console

with log_to_file(sys, LOG_FILE_PATH):
    print("hello")  # Prints to the file

print("hello")  # Prints to the console
```

To build this context manager will be using the following code

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys

@contextmanager
def log_to_file(sys, LOG_FILE_PATH):
    log_file = open(LOG_FILE_PATH, 'a')
    sys.stdout = log_file
    yield
    log_file.close()
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Now you can decide where to write every time simply by passing a different file path and your code will be clean and Pythonic